# Download file with other server

Tags: php, nginx, apache2

Simple question. I have:

1. VPS
2. localhost server (simple)

I have file: `sitemap.xml` on SERVER 1 (vps) AND I want download `sitemap.xml` in SERVER 2 using function ex. `file_get_contents(ip_vps/sitemap.xml)`.

BUT I can't download file or download is long. How configure VPS by GOOD??

PS: I sorry for my English. I try learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this

file_put_contents('server1.xml',file_get_contents('http://othersiteURL.com/sitemap.xml'));

simplexml_load_file('server1.xml');

Comment: Thanks. Problem is on VPS becouse I want download with more serwers. First time download long, second the same and  third time download normal.

Comment: TRy this.. i think not take more load and explore this function..
   copy('http://www.example1.com/', 'yourlocalfile.xml');